# JPA Self referencing entity with relation to sibling join table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have an self referencing entity with children and parent. I have a join table to store the mutually exclusive siblings. When create the entity in the database, I get this exception...

Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

the main table will have

```
ID Text Parent
1  ABC   null
2  CBD    1
3  XYZ    1
```

Join table should have

```
entity sibling
2        3
```

is the Entity mapping correct?

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
   @id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;
   private String Text;
   @ManyToOne
   private TestEntity parent;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="mutuallyExclusiveSiblings",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="entity", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="sibling", referencedColumnName="id")})
        private Set<TestEntity> exclusiveSiblings;


}
```

Any help implementing this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to post the snippet you used to persist the entity.

Comment: You are calling persist() on a detached entity (i.e. on an entity which already has an ID). That's the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to post the actual code due to proprietary confidential info concerns at my place... here is the code for the example above. Thanks for your help.                                TestEntity te = new TestEntity();
    te.setId(4);
    te.setParent(null);
    Set<TestEntity> exsib = new HashSet<TestEntity>();
    te.setExclusiveSiblings(exsib);
    List<TestEnity> ret = new ArrayList<TestEntity>();
    ret = testEntityService.getByText("XXX");
    for(TestEntity t : ret){
            te.getExclusiveSiblings().add(t);
     }
    testEntityService.createRecord(te);

Comment: looking around for a way to format code in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CascadeType.ALL` means that calling persist on an `TestEntity` with some `TestEntity` siblings will trigger the insertion of the test entity AND the sibling test entities.

If either of those already as a Id populated that will cause the error, as persist is only for newly created entities that don't exist yet on the database.

so if you are linking a new `TestEntity` to existing siblings in the database, then it's better to just call persist on the new `TestEntity` without adding the children first.

At that moment the new `TestEntity` will become dirty checked and you can link it to existing siblings, which will trigger inserts in the association table when the session flushes.

Comment: you are right in one of my test both were both table was being inserted. The use case is I want to insert a new TestEntity with id 4, but it will have existing mutually exclusive sibling for example id 2. on create new TestEntity 4 should be created in TestEntity table and ids 4 and 2 should be created in join table. Thanks.